# A problem with Krita

Tags: command-line

```
Legacy integer arithmetics implementation

krita(5850)/kdeui (KIconLoader): Error: standard icon theme "oxygen" not found!

Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-VniZSIc28N,guid=ba4cb51309f8eaeddc2d0a2f00000017" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-VniZSIc28N,guid=ba4cb51309f8eaeddc2d0a2f00000017" 
Registered DEC:  true 
krita(5850)/koffice (lib komain): "krita" part.desktop not found.

krita(5850)/koffice (lib komain): Run 'kde4-config --path services' to see which directories were searched, assuming kde startup had the same environment as your current shell.

krita(5850)/koffice (lib komain): Check your installation (did you install Calligra in a different prefix than KDE, without adding the prefix to /etc/kderc ?)
```

I recently tried installing Krita. I used the command line they provided on the website and this is what I got.

The command line was:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install krita
```

Comment: somehow, it worked.. I installed the latest version of Krita, and it worked :)

Comment: Was there anything different (that you know of) between when it didn't work and when it started working? If so, you may want to [post an answer explaining it](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). If you don't have any idea why the problem went away, then this can no longer be answered (and in that case we can close the question).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing karbon and kde-plasma-dekstop. Instructions can be found [here](http://userbase.kde.org/Krita/Getting_Started/Installing_Krita)

But still, when I run krita from terminal, I still see a huge list of errors.

Note: I am running on elementeryOS.